# Tearing Everywhere on Wayland using Intel Graphics

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, wayland, tearing

If you're going to suggest [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Tearing) as the solution, yes I know that but that's only effective for X11 not Wayland. I looked up for the solution for Wayland or the way to use xorg.conf on Wayland but there are no documents about it.

Symptoms: Tearing happens not only in videos but everywhere where rendering is happening(e.g. shaking application windows).

Device: UHD 630 + 4K/30Hz on HDMI 1.4

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing terrible tearing on wayland (using swayvm) and I've also searched to no avail on how to fix or at least debug it